# flash mp3 player with playlist playing the song that has been deleted or changed

Tags: flash, audio-player

I downloaded player from http://premiumbeat.com but I don't know why what the problem it had with with playlist. I had a playlist in xml file with songs. When i deleted the mp3 from the server, it is still playing. and when i changed the mp3 files it is still playing the original files.

I don't know where these files were saved. I thought it was saved in my browser cache and i cleared it but it didn't work. I thought it was cached in my server, but in my localserver , i had the same problem.

So, again i downloaded the player, and this time it played different song, that i put.

I have a hypothesis. Does flash player (swf object) absorb mp3 files?? i don't think so but how come player is playing the mp3 that has been changed or deleted? if it was in server cache then how long will it take to clear the cache and play new file. However, i don't remember coding something like 'cache';

Can anyone suggest me mp3 music player with playlist(dynamic such that songs can be changed from database *however playlist that can be changed from ftp is also appreciable*) that is quite small and of courser free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change the path to your playlist. You are probably using the default path that points to the default playlist on the server where you bought the player. Look at the instructions on how to point the player to another playlist.

If you are having problems installing this media player, the first thing to try is using absolute paths instead of relative paths. For example,

Instead of using a relative path like below

options.playlistXmlPath = "playlist.xml"
Use a full absolute path:

options.playlistXmlPath = "http://www.yoursite.com/playlist.xml"

Comment: and on xml file should i add the filename or absolute filename path.

Comment: thanks of your effort but it was not the problem.there used to be song in server named song1.mp3 ...  when i delete this song  and upload another song  and rename it song1.mp3 ... and i play it through my browser, what in the world is happening, i am getting the original song.

Comment: What happens if you paste the URL into your browser? Do you get the correct mp3 file?

Comment: Okay! i had a url http://url/song1.mp3 it was my original song. from FTP i deleted and uploaded another song song2.mp3. form my firefox i can browse song2.mp3 and play as new song. but when i re name it song1.mp3 again i get the original(song1.mp3) song. and my host is hostmonster

Comment: yes! it's not from my browser. its from server. I mean i tried to play mp3 file in my browser from server. (rename to original song, new song changes into original)

Comment: I mean ... if you get the correct song in the browser using the song url, then you can be sure the problem is in the music player/xml

Comment: no, player/xml contains only filename. and when filename is changed in xml file without renaming the file to song1.mp3 it works. but if the file is renamed song1.mp3 then original song1.mp3 is played. I think it's server's problem. And thank you for your effort. and sorry for responding so late.

Answer (score 1):

This is how flash works. The first data in the cache loaded will be the only data it will read. Even if you already delete your file, flash already buffered it, so it will still play it. For a simple solution, try "Private Browsing" for chrome or mozilla. But for the real solution, try this:

1. make your playlist.xml dynamic by editing it through php with fopen, fwrite and fclose.
2. save the playlist name, then add random() to the name of the playlist file. It will become "playlist123874.xml"
3. every time flash read your playlist, it will read different filenames but have one content, so it will be refreshed

that's the main idea. try renaming the file you want to play randomly. Check my website [librengmusika.org](http://librengmusika.org)